# how to install confluent-Kafka (python) on windows 10

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

how to install confluent-Kafka Python in windows 10 system along with librdkafka.

I am not able to perform pip install confluent-Kafka in windows it is throwing error that it requires Ms c++ build tools even i have install Ms visual studio 2017 still it is throwing error

Comment: By confluent-kafka, are you referring to the Confluent Platform version of the Kafka broker, or the Confluent.Kafka .NET client, or perhaps the confluent-kafka Python client?

Comment: Means I want to use confluent Kafka in python in windows environment but I am not able to perform pip install confluent-Kafka in windows it is throwing error that it requires Ms c++ build tools even i have install Ms visual studio 2017 still it is throwing error. thank . https://stackoverflow.com/users/1821055/edenhill

Answer (score 4):

confluent-kafka-python is not yet available for Windows.

There's been some community effort to build and run it, see this github issue:
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/132#issuecomment-327574752

Answer (score -1):

you can run it in windows. Below is window patch on github for confluent 5.0.1.

https://github.com/mduhan/confluent-windows-5.0.1

Comment: 1) That's not Python 2) Confluent Platform has been working on my Windows machine 3) It would be better if it were merged back to the main repo